# I'm trying to run a file but VBS cant find the file im triyng to run

Tags: vbscript

I'm triyng to run a file file through VBS as Administrator and it can unfortunatly not find the file here is the command i'm running

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
  Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
  ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
    , """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End if
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("C:\Users\David\Desktop\X-tra Settings\File.bat")
```

And it can't find the file. I've tried a few things. It's in the same folder as the VBS file, but it won't find it.

Comment: You quoted the `ScriptFullName`, why didn't you quote your batch file? Also, remove the parenthesis in the `run` method call.

Comment: I qouted ScriptFullName because i will get errors if i don't

Comment: So, why do you think the path to the batch file does not deserve the same care?

Comment: @MCND or prefix it with `Call` like `Call CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run ("""C:\Users\David\Desktop\X-tra Settings\File.bat""")`.

Comment: @Lankymart, I just decided between removal of non needed elements or inclusion of an additional instruction to correct the usage of a non needed element (just my point of view). Of course you are right, thank you. (note: I know some programmers that prefer the explicit `Call` as they find it cleaner, but appart from coding style, do you know any reason to prefer the use of this construct?)

Comment: @MCND Cleaner is definitely the main reason. Imo procedures should always be contained in brackets. It's entirely down to coding style though and there is no wrong / right way.

Answer (score 0):

To quote your variable, i recommend you to use this function :

```
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
```

And your code looks like this one :

```
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , ""& DblQuote(WScript.ScriptFullName) &" /elevate","","runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If
Set Ws = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Ws.Run DblQuote("%userprofile%\Desktop\X-tra Settings\File.bat"),1,True
'****************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'****************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space in the command line. This:

```
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe" _
, """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """
```

Needs to be this (notice the added space after wscript.exe):

```
ObjShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe " _
, """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """
```

otherwise it's trying to execute this:

```
wscript.exe"C:\Users\David\Desktop\X-tra Settings\File.vbs"
```

which it won't be able to find